# Matching Router URL with current URL in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code that lists tags for a blog built in CakePHP:

```
$tagsList = $this->requestAction('/tags/listTags');
foreach ($tagsList as $tagsListTag) {
    echo '<li'. strpos($this->here, Router::url(array('controller'=>'tags','action'=>'view','slug'=>$tagsListTag['Tag']['slug'])) ? ' class="selected"' : '' ).'>'.$this->Html->link($tagsListTag['Tag']['title'],array('controller'=>'tags','action'=>'view','slug'=>$tagsListTag['Tag']['slug']),array('class'=>'tag')).'</li>';
}
```

I've added a bit of logic that compares the current URL, with what the Router URL for each link would be and if it matches should add a class of `selected` to the `<li>`

However it's not worked, even though echoing just the `$this->here` and `Router::url` show them to be the same! Is their some other issue here with the way I am adding the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your parentheses aren't set correctly, your code snippet will produce a parser error. I assume this mistake only exists in this code example? It should look something like this:

```
'<li' . (strpos($this->here, Router::url(array(...))) ? ' class="selected"' : '') . '>'
```

The other problem would be that [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) can return `0` (`needle` is found at position `0` in `haystack`) as well as boolean `false` (`needle` not found), and since `0` evaluates to false (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) your condition will fail in case the URL matches at the first char.

So you either have to test for `0` too, or compare the values differently. When testing for URLs you most probably want to match the exact URL, so you could simply use the comparison operator `===` instead:

```
$this->here === Router::url(...)
```

In case you need to match only parts of the URL, you could stay with `strpos` and match strictly against `0`:

```
(strpos($this->here, Router::url(array(...))) === 0 ? '...' : '...')
```

This would match the exact URL, as well as all URLs that start with `needle`.

Comment: Not getting any parser errors? Code is exactly as posted! Also could you show an example how to test for 0 as well. I need to use strpos over the comparison in case the URL has variations e.g. `/tags/PHP` or `/tags/PHP/page/2`

Comment: In that case a strict comparison against `0` should do it, I'll add an example.